# Please help me, I am unable to update my note taking app api using CRUD

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

This is the tools.py

```
from .models import Note
from .serializers import NoteSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404



def getNoteslist(request):
    notes=Note.objects.all().order_by('-updated')
    serializer=NoteSerializer(notes, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def NoteDetail(request, pk):
    notedetail=get_object_or_404(Note,id=pk)
    serializer=NoteSerializer(notedetail, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def createNote(request):
    data=request.data
    note=Note.objects.create(
    title=data['title'],
    body=data['body']
    )
    serializer=NoteSerializer(note, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def updateNote(request, pk):

    note=Note.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer=NoteSerializer(instance=note, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)

def delete(request, pk):
    note=get_object_or_404(Note,id=pk)
    note.delete()
    return Response('Note is deleted!')
```

This is the views.py

```
from .models import Note
from .tools import getNoteslist,NoteDetail,updateNote,createNote,delete
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['GET'])
def getNotes(request):
    return getNoteslist(request)
@api_view(['POST'])  
def createNotes(request):
    return createNote(request)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getNote(request,pk):
    return NoteDetail(request, pk)

@api_view(['POST'])   
def updateNote(request, pk):
    return updateNote(request, pk)

@api_view(['DELETE'])
def delNote(request, pk):
    return delete(request, pk)
```

This is the urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

schema_view=get_swagger_view(title='NOTE TAKING APi')
API_TITLE='NOTE TAKING APi'
API_DESCRIPTION='A note taking API for creating and editing notes.'

urlpatterns=[
path('',views.getNotes,name='Notes'),
path('create/',views.createNotes,name='Notes'),
path('<int:pk>/',views.getNote,name='note'),
path('update/<int:pk>/',views.updateNote,name='note'),
path('delete/<int:pk>/',views.delNote,name='note'),
path('docs/',include_docs_urls(title=API_TITLE, 
description=API_DESCRIPTION)),
path('swagger-docs/',schema_view)
]
```

here is the error:

```
**Internal Server Error: /Note/update/4/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in 
_get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in 
_get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\DJANGO\api\NoteTaking\Note\views.py", line 20, in updateNote  
    return updateNote(request, pk)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 391, in initialize_request
    return Request(
  File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 154, in __init__
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest), (
AssertionError: The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`.**
```

Comment: What exactly is your specific question? Please read [Why is "*Can someone help me?*" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: could you add `.as_view()` behind your views in urls.py? Like `views.updateNote.as_view()`

Comment: AssertionError: The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`.**

Comment: I am not using a class-based view

Comment: Your view is named `updateNote` _and_ the function it calls it is named `updateNote`. You are simply recursively calling your view...

Answer (score 0):

i got the same errors when i tried it.

The only solution i found was, to write everything in the view directly, so changing:

```
@api_view(['POST'])   
def updateNote(request, pk):
    return updateNote(request, pk)
```

to:

```
@api_view(['POST'])   
def updateNote(request, pk):
    note=Note.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer=NoteSerializer(instance=note, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

worked for me

i don't know why it has problems calling another function

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that functions have clashing names. Change the name updateNote in either views.py or in tools.py